# cygwin installer claims that some boost libraries are installed but no header files found under C:\cygwin64

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin

I have installed cygwin64 on windows 11 in folder
C:\cygwin64
Then I installed some boost libraries ex libboost_program_options1.66
I can also see that in the temporary folder for installation a
libboost_program_options1.66-1.66.0-1.tar.xz
is downloaded.
But I cannot find any *.hpp files related to boost.
How do I install the header files?

Comment: Use MSYS2 and install boost with using their packages

Comment: I don't remember for sure if Cygwin does the same, but most distros have separate dev packages for libraries that install headers and/or static libraries.  The non-dev packages generally just have the runtime components of the library.

Comment: Yes you are right. To get the header files ons has to install libboost-devel

Comment: `I have installed cygwin64`, that was your first mistake, cygwin really isn't that useful anymore, if you want a Linux environment just use wsl, msys is another option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Development packages are usually named `*-devel`
for boost you need to install `libboost-devel`package

See also
http://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/libboost-devel.html
http://www.cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libboost-devel/libboost-devel-1.66.0-1